# Error converting to float -- How to screen out bad values

Tags: sql-server

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have a table with all columns set up as `varchar(255)`, which is necessary since I do data validation on this table.  I have the following query on this table:

```
SELECT
    col_1
FROM 
    table_A
WHERE
    col_1 NOT LIKE '%[^.0123456789]%'
    AND CAST(col_1 AS float) <= 2.5
```

I'm getting an error stating that it can't convert one of my table values to data type float. The offending value is '3269e+'. I don't understanding why this value causes an error. Wouldn't this value have been excluded by the first condition in the `WHERE` clause? If I'm doing something wrong, how should I re-write this query?

Comment: You can't control the order that predicates are applied in your where clause. You will have to split this into two queries for this to work, first query will be the first predicate, then you can apply the math portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse out the string using a like statement, you can use [ISNUMERIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx). This does have some false positives, which people discuss on the comments of the MSDN page. In your example, it could be:

```
SELECT
    col_1
FROM 
    table_A
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(col_1) = 1
    AND CAST(col_1 AS float) <= 2.5
```

Comment: My solution was to use the ISNUMERIC test in addition to my string test.  I do my string test because I know that ISNUMERIC can fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cte to first separate the valid rows, then apply your math.

```
with ValidRows as
(
    SELECT
    col_1
    FROM table_A
    WHERE col_1 NOT LIKE '%[^.0123456789]%'
)

select *
from ValidRows
WHERE CAST(col_1 AS float) <= 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

No it wont be taken out by the first condition. that order of execution is done by query optimizer.

Tf you want to make it work you could use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT col_1
    FROM table_A
    WHERE col_1 NOT LIKE '%[^.0123456789]%' ) t
WHERE CAST(col_1 AS float) <= 2.5
```

Here is a working version with data similar to yours:

```
DECLARE @value AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '1'
DECLARE @value1 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '2.1'
DECLARE @value2 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '1.5'
DECLARE @value3 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '32344'
DECLARE @value4 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '23324e+'
DECLARE @value5 AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '23434334e+'

select * from(
    select @value as v
    UNION
    select @value1
    UNION
    select @value2
    UNION
    select @value3
    UNION
    select @value4
    UNION
    select @value5
) t
where t.v NOT LIKE '%[^.0123456789]%'
AND CAST(t.v AS float) <= 2.5
```

Comment: I tried this sub-query idea.  It didn't work for me.  It's still saying 'Error converting data type varchar to float'.  (When I use int instead of float, it lets me know that the value in error is '3269e+'.  I'm assuming that is the only offending value for the float as well.)

Comment: @SeanLange I updated the answer with a working query. it could be some other data that is not castable if it does not work for you...